# Ringer Mode Changing App doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a small app that takes input from the user in the form of a TimePicker, stores it in variables, that are later used to trigger an alarm which will keep the ringer at the desired mode until required.

But everytime I try running it on the AVD, it keeps crashing whenever I press any button, either silent or vibrate.

The MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.android.implementingringermechanism;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;    
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//TimePicker to take time input from user when dialog activity pops
TimePicker picker;
//Buttons to change mode to silent or vibrate
Button silentButton, vibrateButton;
//Variables to store hours and minutes chosen by user
private int hour, minute;

//AudioManager instance used to change ringer mode
private AudioManager mAudioManager;

//AlarmManager instance used to set alarm to background task
AlarmManager mgr;

//Calendar instance to manipulate time for alarm with user input
Calendar time;

//PendingIntent to start when alarm is finished
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    //TimePicker will show time in 24 hour mode
    picker.setIs24HourView(true);
    silentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.silentButton);
    vibrateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vibrateButton);

    //AlarmManager instance created to set an alarm for changing ringer mode back to normal
    mgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    time = Calendar.getInstance();
    time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

}

public void silent(View view){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        hour = picker.getHour();
        minute = picker.getMinute();
    }
    else {
        hour = picker.getCurrentHour();
        minute = picker.getCurrentMinute();
    }
    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Silent mode till " + hour + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    time.add(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    time.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}

public void vibrate(View view) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        hour = picker.getHour();
        minute = picker.getMinute();
    }
    else {
        hour = picker.getCurrentHour();
        minute = picker.getCurrentMinute();
    }
    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Vibrate mode till " + hour + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    time.add(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    time.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
}
```

The activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="273dp"
    android:layout_height="368dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/silentButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:text="@string/silentText"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="silent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vibrateButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="@string/vibrateText"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="vibrate"
        />


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.implementingringermechanism">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/setTime"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
</manifest>
```

The MyAlarmReceiver.java file:

```
package com.example.android.implementingringermechanism;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

private AudioManager AM;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    AM.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Ringer Mode changed to Normal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

For now, the problem I'm encountering is that on app startup, the dialog box appears, but pressing any of the two buttons makes it crash.

Comment: a part from audio manager null,onRecive will not do RINGER_MODE_NORMAL when your app is in background state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because of two reasons:

1. Your AudioManager is null. Add this code to your onCreate():

   mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
2. If you're testing on a device that's running Android Marshmallow or higher, you'll need to request permission from the user before you're able to set the ringer mode. You can gain that request by adding this code:

   ```
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M 
           && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
       startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Sir if you are testing on higher android api you need to add ask administrator previlagers first

```
    private void fornougat() {

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N
            && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I invoke this function?

Comment: IN onCreate this permission should be  asked first then you should change ringer mode